# Progress Bar With Minimal Network Traffic

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion, internet-explorer-8, websocket

**Short version of question:**
I need to show progress of a process back to the user.  I would love to use WebSockets but I have to support all the way back to IE8.  Since I can't use WebSockets am I stuck using a JavaScript `setTimeout` and doing pings? Are there any new techniques out there I haven't heard of yet?  I'm looking for a solution (not a detailed solution, just a name of a technique or technology I haven't heard of yet if there is one) that doesn't involve so much network traffic.

**Long version:**
I have a handful of progress bars in my application.  They work by doing a `$.post` to start some process.  That process does it's job and along the way it sets a few session variables stating it's progress, records processes, filesize, etc...  Immediately after that initial `$.post` I also start a "heartbeat" or "ping" process that goes and gets these session variables in order to show the user % complete, records processes, and current filesize.  It fires every 1/2 second so the user sees the progress bar increment smoothly, the number of records processed increments smoothly, and they see the size of the resulting PDF grow in real time.  Its been working great for years.  The front end of the ping process looks like this...

```
function rptCheckProgress(id)
{
    jQuery.ajax({
        async:false,
        cache:false,
        url: 'rpt.cfc?method=rptCheckProgress&rptId='+id,
        success: function(data)
        {
            jQuery('#libRptProgress').html(data);
            if (!gStopHeartBeat) setTimeout("rptCheckProgress("+id+");", 500);
        }
    });
}
```

Now I have to implement more scenarios like this that require a "ping" to show progress.  I really hate doing so many mini pings especially since the networks where our software is used is VERY slow but I don't know of another way.  I would love to use WebSockets but I have to support all the way back to IE8.  Since I can't use WebSockets am I stuck using a JavaScript `setTimeout` and doing pings?

Answer (score 2):

Use [socket.io](http://socket.io), it uses WebSockets when possible, but falls back to Long Polling. If you don't want to use socket.io, use Long Polling directly.

Comment: I've been reading up on this and there isn't much documentation on installation.  Now I have heard of node.js before, but was under the impression that it was for only modern HTML5 browsers but I saw in a post that node.js uses socket.io.  So should I just use node.js instead?  On socket.io the install instructions appear to be for UNIX.  I'm on Windows.  Is this another service or webserver that runs along side Apache?  I thought this stuff was just JavaScript code that I add to my current app but it appears that something has to be installed.  I'll read up some more, just not clicking yet.

Comment: You have to use some sort of web server. Using Apache for things like pushing updates from the server to the browser isn't a very good idea so many developers are migrating to other web servers like NodeJS. If you really want to start async programming you should consider switching to ;)

Comment: In your case i'd recommend just using long polling, if you're really using cold fusion maybe [that](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1976-Long-Polling-Experiment-With-jQuery-And-ColdFusion.htm) works

Answer (score 1):

ColdFusion's implementation of Websockets has a fall back too. I believe it falls back on Flash... which means its not going to cover all devices, like socket.io claims to do.

I have heard good things about ColdFusion's Websockets, its not seen in the same light as CFFORM etc, but usually doing it yourself in JS is sometimes the best bet.
I have heard of socket.io, but I do not know anymore than that.

I would not try to re-invent the wheel, and WebSockets are designed for this, so utilizing them with their fallbacks would give you the best possible scenario on newer browsers, and the traditional long polling for those browsers like IE8 that need it.

Depending on your needs, one of those should help you solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks.  I saw this warning though (it's pretty recent)<http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2013/06/security-warning-stop-using-coldfusion.html> And I cannot code to CF10 yet either cause the gov't lags sooo faaarrrr beeeehhhiinnnnnndddddddd :/ But I didn't know about this new websocket tag, thanks for letting me know of it.  Maybe in 10years our customers will let me use it :) jk

Comment: That was in response to a security issue. Adobe were johnny on the spot on this one, and actually releaed a bug fix soon after. It was a point and case on how community involvement can force Adobes hand. It properly patched now, this is not an issue. Adam Cameron has a follow up blog that confirms this. I'll try and locate it later.

Answer (score 0):

**Server-Sent Events** might be an option today:

> Developing a web application that uses server-sent events is easier
>   than with websockets. You'll need a bit of code on the server to
>   stream events to the front-end, but the client side code works almost
>   identically to handling any other event.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events